# What difference between syntax-quote in Clojure and syntax-quote in Clojurescript?

Tags: clojure, macros, clojurescript, read-eval-print-loop

In Clojure REPL:

```clj
(macroexpand-1 `(sum 2 1)) ; (user/sum 2 1)
```

In Clojurescript REPL:

```clj
(macroexpand-1 `(sum 2 1)) ; AssertionError: Assert failed: Argument to macroexpand-1 must be quoted
```

Why it happens? Can you explain evalutation process in Clojurescript please?

Comment: perhaps relevant: https://clojurescript.org/about/differences#_macros

Comment: You have to use a quote, not a backtick `(macroexpand-1 '(sum 2 1)) `

Comment: @akond yeah, but how it works? :)

Comment: [Syntax quote](https://clojure.org/reference/reader#syntax-quote) is a little bit different when it comes to symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Clojure, `macroexpand-1` can be a function, because Clojure has access to the compiler at runtime, so `macroexpand-1` can inspect any list you construct. Clojurescript is compiled to Javascript, and doesn't have access to the compiler at runtime. So macroexpand is only useful at compile-time, and must be a macro in order to run then. It therefore doesn't evaluate its argument, and needs it to be a literal quoted list.

You might now ask: "Doesn't syntax-quote return a quoted list?". But it doesn't. It returns some expression that evaluates to the right list; in principle it could return a quoted list when you don't use any unquoting, but in practice it doesn't. You can see this in the repl by quoting a syntax-quoted expression, to see its expansion instead of evaluating it:

In a Clojure repl:

```
user=> '`(sum 1 2)
(clojure.core/seq (clojure.core/concat (clojure.core/list (quote user/sum)) (clojure.core/list 1) (clojure.core/list 2)))
```

In a Clojurescript repl:

```
user=> '`(sum 1 2)
(cljs.core/sequence (cljs.core/concat (clojure.core/list (quote cljs.user/sum)) (clojure.core/list 1) (clojure.core/list 2)))
```